# MongoDB - is this efficient?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection `users` in mongodb. I am using the node/mongodb API.

In my node.js if I go:

`var users = db.collection("users");`

and then

`users.findOne({ ... })`

Is this idiomatic and efficient?

I want to avoid loading all users into application memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mongo, `collection.find()` returns a `cursor`, which is an abstract representation of the results that match your query. It doesn't return your results over the wire until you iterate over the cursor by calling `cursor.next()`. Before iterating over it, you can, for instance, call `cursor.limit(x)` to limit the number of results that it is allowed to return.

`collection.findOne()` is effectively just a shortcut version of `collection.find().limit(1).next()`. So the cursor is never allowed to return more than the one result.

As already explained, the `collection` object itself is a facade allowing access to the collection, but which doesn't hold any actual documents in memory.

`findOne()` is very efficient, and it is indeed idiomatic, though IME it's more used in dev/debugging than in real application code.  It's very useful in the CLI, but how often does a real application need to just grab any one document from a collection?  The only case I can think of is when a given query can only ever return one document (i.e. an effective primary key).

Further reading:
[Cursors](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/),
[Read Operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should only load one user into memory.

The collection object is exactly that, it doesn't return all users when you create a new collection object, only when you either use a `findOne` or you iterate a cursor from the return of a `find`.

Comment: Thanks. Why do I need to specify the collection in this way. Can I not simply supply a query direct to the database. e.g. `db.query({ /* my query possibly involving multiple collections */ })`?

Comment: @Ben because the mongodb server cannot query multiple collections/commands in the same space. It requires one command at a time per collection.

Comment: Sammaye  -  and you have to combine the results of collection queries in application memory?

Comment: @Ben indeed, MongoDB has no joins